# C++ import loop with two classes?

Tags: c++, class, import, compiler-errors

*I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find it.*

I have two classes, `Vector` and `Point`.

The files are as such (a bit repetitive):

`vector.h`:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Vector {
  friend class Point;

  public:
    ...

    Vector(Point); // Line 16
```

`vector.cpp`:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "vector.h"

...

Vector::Vector(Point point) { // Line 29
  x = point.x;
  y = point.y;
  z = point.z;
}
```

`point.cpp` and `point.h` look mostly the same, except you swap `vector` with `point` in the definitions.

I include them as such:

```
#include "structures/vector.cpp"
#include "structures/point.cpp"
```

---

When I compile, I get this error:

```
structures/vector.h:16:17: error: field ‘Point’ has incomplete type
structures/vector.cpp:29:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
```

I think this error is saying that `Point` hasn't been declared yet, but when I declare it inside of `vector.h` by importing `point.cpp`, I get a *huge* pile of errors.

Could anyone shed some light on this problem?

Thank you!

---

Upon applying @ildjarn's suggestions, those errors went away and I am left with this single one:

```
structures/vector.h:16:18: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
```

And the line:

```
Vector(Point const);
```

I define it like so in the `.cpp` file:

```
Vector::Vector(Point const &point) {
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ cyclic inclusion issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685220/c-cyclic-inclusion-issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You shouldn't be including .cpp files, you should be including the .h files.
2. vector.cpp needs `#include "point.h"` and (presumably) point.cpp needs `#include "vector.h"`.
3. A forward declaration is only sufficient if you're not doing anything that requires the type's size or interface. Because `Vector`'s constructor is taking a `Point` by value, its size must be known; change `Vector`'s constructor to take the `Point` by `const` reference instead and a forward declaration will remain sufficient.
4. Your headers need [#include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) (or [`#pragma once`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) if you don't mind not being 100% portable).

---

**EDIT** (in response to OP's edit):

Your declaration and definitions now mismatch -- i.e., your definition is correct but your declaration needs `Point const&` rather than just `Point const`.

Comment: That error went away, thank you! Now a less-cryptic one has arisen (YES!!!) See my question again for that one.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I really appreciate the input. I tried it, but I seem to be getting the same results.

Comment: @Blender : Then please post an accurate copy of your updated code. Note that the forward declaration is still necessary.

Comment: I tried putting the ampersand in almost every place in this line: `Vector(Point const&);`.

Comment: My code was so bad I just rewrote the whole program from scratch with your suggestions. Thanks for the input!